# Error while trying to deploy a spring 5 app in wildlfy26.1.2

Tags: java, spring, deployment, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy spring 5 application in wildlfy 26.1.2. JDK version is 1.8

19:46:45,930 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ECP2P.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ECP2P.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet spring of type class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet does not implement jakarta.servlet.Servlet**
at io.undertow.servlet.api.ServletInfo.(ServletInfo.java:98)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:749)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:312)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)

Answer (score 0):

Spring 5 is JakartaEE 9 or 10 , so you either need to use WildFly 27 or 26-preview.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to use spring 5, then we need to use Jakarta EE 8 Full & Web Distribution of wildlfy 26.1.2 not WildFly Preview EE 9.1 Distribution. I was using preview, hence above error.